# How can you print multiple ArrayLists next to each other

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of an Object I called Process and each process has an arrayList of integers for allocation, max and need, so each process essentially has 3 arraylists to it. I am trying to make a table that looks like this

```
              Allocation       Max           Need
 Process 1    1 2 3 4          1 2 3 4     1 2 3 4 
 Process 2    5 7 8 9          5 7 8 9     5 7 8 9 
 Process 3    1 2 3 4          1 2 3 4     1 2 3 4 
 Process 4    5 7 8 9          5 7 8 9     5 7 8 9
```

etc
each number is it's own slot so the size of all of the arrays of is 4. This is my code I am trying

```
 public String toString() {
    String temp = "";
    String tempAllo = "";
    String tempMax = "";
    String tempNeed = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < allocation.size(); j++) {
        tempAllo = allocation.get(j).toString() + " ";
        tempMax = max.get(j).toString() + " ";
        tempNeed = need.get(j).toString() + " ";
    }

    temp = id + "\t" + tempAllo + "\t" + tempMax + "\t" + tempNeed + "\n";

    return temp;
}
```

but it prints out

```
                   Allocation       Max           Need
     Process 1        4             4              4 
     Process 2        9             9              9 
     Process 3        4             4              4
     Process 4        9             9              9
```

so it is only printing out the last one. Thank you in advanced for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be: (note the `+=`)

```
tempAllo += allocation.get(j).toString() + " ";
tempMax += need.get(j).toString() + " ";
tempNeed += allocation.get(j).toString() + " ";
```

I would suggest you to use a `StringBuilder` for variables `temp`, `tempAllo`,.. instead of a `String`.

So that you could do,

```
tempAllo.append(allocation.get(j).toString()).append(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for (int j = 0; j < allocation.size(); j++) {
    tempAllo = tempAllo.concat(allocation.get(j).toString() + " ");
    tempMax = tempMax.concat(need.get(j).toString() + " ");
    tempNeed = tempNeed.concat(allocation.get(j).toString() + " ");
}
```